# Pyside6, Qt Designer and class inheritance (Python)

Tags: python, inheritance, qt5, pyside6

I'm developing a small app using Python 3.9.7, PySide 6.5.0, Qt Designer 6.4.2, VSCode 1.74.3.

I managed to create a widget using Qt Designer and converting it to a `py` file using `pyuic6` command. This widget is used to insert or update a record inside an SQlite database.

This is an extract of the code generated by QtDesigner/pyuic6

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_insertCode(object):
    def setupUi(self, insertCode):
        insertCode.setObjectName("insertCode")
        insertCode.resize(626, 174)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(insertCode)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout.setObjectName("codeNavigationGridLayout")
        self.fieldLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=insertCode)
        self.fieldLineEdit.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum,                                     
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.fieldLineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.fieldLineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.fieldLineEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        ...
```

This in the constructor of the class that uses the previous ui

```
class updateCode(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_insertCode):
    '''
    widget that implements updating code into database    
    '''

    def __init__(self, sibling=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Update code...")
        self.sibling = sibling
        if self.sibling:
            logging.debug("Added sibling to updateCode class.")
        ...
```

In the main widget (that is NOT a QMainWindow) I have a button whose clicked signal is connected to calling function of the previous widget

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime, date
import config
import logging
import config

from resources import resources
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

# from my_components.qtexteditlogger import QTextEditLogger

from my_components.first_tab import Ui_firstTab
from my_components.components import QTextEditLogger, addCode, updateCode

# initial database setup

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName(
    'E:/database.sqlite3')
if not db.open():
    print('Error opening database {}'.format(db.databaseName))
db.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")


class firstTab(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_firstTab):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(firstTab, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.logHandler = QTextEditLogger(self.logWidget)
        self.logHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))

        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.logHandler)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        self.setupCode()
        self.setupSerial()

        logging.info("Loading UI done!")

        self.codeEditButton.clicked.connect(self.code_edit_record)
        
        ...

    def code_edit_record(self):
        logging.debug("update code")
        self.code_child = updateCode(sibling=self, parent=None)
        self.code_child.show()
        
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    window = firstTab()
    window.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With this code everything works, but I have to pass `sibiling` object as parameter to the constructor of `updateCode` class

If implement this

```
class updateCode(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_insertCode):
    '''
    widget that implements updating code into database    
    '''

    def __init__(self, sibling=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Update code...")
        self.sibling = sibling
        if self.sibling:
            logging.debug("Added sibling to updateCode class.")
```

and call it like

```
self.code_child = updateCode(sibling=self, parent=None)
```

or

```
self.code_child = updateCode(sibling=None, parent=self)
```

I get this error in the `super().__init(parent)` of the `child_code`class

```
super().__init__(parent)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

So the questions are

- Why I get this error also when calling `self.code_child = updateCode(sibling=None, parent=self)`
- Which is te best method to get access from a widget to another ?

**EDIT**

I try to add a working (or not working!) example...

`insertcode.py` (generated by pyuic6)

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_insertCode(object):
    def setupUi(self, insertCode):
        insertCode.setObjectName("insertCode")
        insertCode.resize(259, 46)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(insertCode)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout.setObjectName("codeNavigationGridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.resetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=insertCode)
        self.resetButton.setObjectName("resetButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.resetButton)
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=insertCode)
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.saveButton)
        self.cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=insertCode)
        self.cancelButton.setObjectName("cancelButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)
        self.codeNavigationGridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.codeNavigationGridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(insertCode)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(insertCode)

    def retranslateUi(self, insertCode):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        insertCode.setWindowTitle(_translate("insertCode", "Form"))
        self.resetButton.setText(_translate("insertCode", "Reset"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("insertCode", "Save"))
        self.cancelButton.setText(_translate("insertCode", "Cancel"))
```

`components.py`

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql
from insertcode import Ui_insertCode


class addCode(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_insertCode):

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class updateCode(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_insertCode):

    def __init__(self, sibling=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.sibling = sibling
        self.setupUi(self)
```

`first_tab.py` (generated by pyuic6)

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_firstTab(object):
    def setupUi(self, firstTab):
        firstTab.setObjectName("firstTab")
        firstTab.resize(281, 252)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(firstTab)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridCode = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridCode.setObjectName("gridCode")
        self.codeTableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(parent=firstTab)
        self.codeTableView.setObjectName("codeTableView")
        self.gridCode.addWidget(self.codeTableView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.codeEditButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=firstTab)
        self.codeEditButton.setObjectName("codeEditButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.codeEditButton)
        self.codeAddButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=firstTab)
        self.codeAddButton.setObjectName("codeAddButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.codeAddButton)
        self.codeDeleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=firstTab)
        self.codeDeleteButton.setObjectName("codeDeleteButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.codeDeleteButton)
        self.gridCode.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridCode, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(firstTab)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(firstTab)

    def retranslateUi(self, firstTab):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        firstTab.setWindowTitle(_translate("firstTab", "Form"))
        self.codeEditButton.setText(_translate("firstTab", "EDIT"))
        self.codeAddButton.setText(_translate("firstTab", "ADD"))
        self.codeDeleteButton.setText(_translate("firstTab", "DELETE"))
```

`so_main.py`

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtSql
from first_tab import Ui_firstTab
from components import addCode, updateCode


class firstTab(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_firstTab):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(firstTab, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.codeEditButton.clicked.connect(self.code_edit_record)
        self.codeAddButton.clicked.connect(self.code_add_record)
        self.codeDeleteButton.clicked.connect(self.code_delete_record)

    def code_edit_record(self):
        self.code_child = updateCode(sibling=self, parent=None)
        self.code_child.show()

    def code_add_record(self):
        self.code_child = addCode(parent=self)
        self.code_child.show()

    def code_delete_record(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    window = firstTab()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With this setup "updateCode" instance will show, but "addCode" raise the error

```
super().__init__(parent)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

This is a very simplified version. With "updateCode" or "addCode" I need to access the QTableView contained in "firstTab" widget.

Comment: That should not happen. Did you try to make any change to the `Ui_insertCode` class? Please provide a complete and self contained [mre].

Comment: You claim this code works, but there's an obvious problem: you check if the database is open, but if it isn't, all you do is print an error message, then proceed as if the database *is* open.

Comment: After your comment I noticed what you mean. The code works for me because I have the database, but you don't... I have edited my first post adding an example where I did not use database at all but SO delete the part where I wrote "***EDIT***"... just before the row "I try to add a working (or not working!) example..."

Comment: I think your error has nothing common with database. I faced the same error today after an upgrade to python 3.11. I have very simple code, it works for python 3.10 but fails with the same TypeError in python 3.11.

Comment: I just checked and see you have python 3.9 and PySide 6.5.0. I have python 3.10 + PySide 6.4.3 and no problem. But with python 3.11 and PySide 6.5.0 I have the same problem. So it appears something is wrong with PySide 6.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that one of your superclasses need a parameter to `__init__`, and is fully collaborative, passing this parameter on - and the other one does not even have a `__init__`, and will pass all parameters it gets to its superclass, which is `object` . Which in turn will error if it gets any argument in `__init__` other than `self`.

The solution seens to simply create an  `__init__` method on your `UI_firstTab` class that will take any extra arguments and ignore then.

```
class UI_firstTab:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super.__init__()
    # keep the rest as is
```

If that still does not work, this means there maybe more differences in the inheritance order there: you will have to inspect the `__mro__` of the created classes, and put some similar code to drop extra arguments on the top-most class in the hierarchy (even creating an extra Base class only for that if that is the case)

**update**

> the problem with this approach is - Ui_firstTab is an augenerated file. It is created with utility 'uic' based on ui-file created with Qt Designer.

Since `UI_firstTab` is autogenerated, and one can't simply add an `__init__` method in there, the solution lies in adding the same `__init__` method to a subclass of that, created in a file under your control. And then use this subclass instead of the original:

```
...
from first_tab import Ui_firstTab
...

class Intermediate(Ui_FirstTab):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__()

class firstTab(QtWidgets.QWidget, Intermediate):
    ...
```

As for why it works in different PySide versions: I don't know as well. Python 3.11 made a lot of optimizations in the inner workings, with some care not to break things up - but it is likely that some corner cases leaked. One thing that has always been delicate is whether Python will ignore extra arguments to objects `__new__` or `__init__` methods: if a class hierarchy never re-implements `__new__`, extra arguments getting to it are ignored (the reasoning is that these extra arguments where likely used in users `__init__` methods already - no reason to force one to create a `__new__` method just to filter out arguments every time one has a parameter to `__init__`). If one of the intermediary classes there got a custom `__new__` method this kind of behavior could arise.

Comment: Hi, the problem with this approach is - Ui_firstTab is an augenerated file. It is created with utility 'uic' based on ui-file created with Qt Designer. And everything works with python 3.10, not problem at all. But with python 3.11 it raises a TypeError. 
I think modification of autogenerated files are not a good option here.

Comment: One mistake I did. It is not about python version but about PySide6 6.5.0.
I have tested - everything works with PySide6 6.4.3 but fails with PySide6 6.5.0 (There is a bug report PYSIDE-2294 on this subject but it isn't commented yet)

Comment: Nice. I've erased the considerations about Python versions from the update above. 

Did that work?

Comment: With PySide 6.5.0 I was able to run it with super().__init__() but... I still try to figure out how to do it if I have different parameters for different parent constuctors...

Comment: The usual thing with multiple inheritance is to design your constructors so that each class will consume the parameters it need, ignore those that are not needed, and pass them away to the superclasses, as they are. The fact is that the generated class you got there explicitly inherits from `object` and don't consume any parameters: so you can't have any other parameter when the call chain reaches there: that is what I do in my last example - it just have to be placed to the right in the class base listing, so they are called last.

Comment: I think you described everything in a good way. But I just got to know that super().__init__(self) shouldn't take self as an argument. It should be super().__init__() I think in your example.

Comment: yes. `self` is added automatically in the parameterless `super()` call. I will fix it.